# How to create a function in PL/SQL and return output

Tags: function, stored-procedures, plsql

I am try to create a function that will table input to function and return me output

**My code :**

```
create or replace function details(keyword varchar2 , depid varchar2 )
return clob 

AS
     v_lst CLOB :='';

BEGIN 

select regexp_replace(
         xmlcast(xmlagg(xmlelement(e, 
           'select ''' || table_name || ''' as tbl, count(*) as cnt from '
           || table_name, ' union all ' || chr(10))) as clob),
       ' union all ' || chr(10) ||'$', ';')
       as sql_string
from   ( SELECT table_name from my_tables where DPNAME := keyword and DEPD := depid);

return v_lst;

EXCEPTION 
    WHEN NO_DATA_FOUND THEN RETURN '';

END;
```

**Trying to call my function**

```
 select details('XYZ' , 24 , : RESULT) as RES from dual;
```

Some compile error getting

**Expected output :**

```
The function will return the dynamic query for me
```

Comment: The first compilation error after fixing the `:=` typos might be *PLS-00428: an INTO clause is expected in this SELECT statement*.

Answer (score 0):

Well, this can't work as `ALL_TABLES` don't contain `DPNAME` nor `DPED` columns. What are they?  And what are function's parameters?

---

What exactly are you trying to do? Count number of rows in all tables available to you?

If so, then

- you should **gather statistics**
- query `ALL_TABLES`' `NUM_ROWS` column

For example:

```
SQL> exec dbms_stats.gather_schema_stats('SCOTT');

PL/SQL procedure successfully completed.

SQL> select table_name, num_rows from user_tables;

TABLE_NAME                       NUM_ROWS
------------------------------ ----------
EMP                                    14
DEPT                                    4
TUSER                                   4
TRANSACTION                            11
TABLE_DATE                             38
<snip>
```

Comment: for demo purpose i taken that but i will replace it with my actual table

Comment: It is difficult to debug a hypothetical function. Post something that compiles (that includes sample data, if necessary).

Comment: currently i cannot share the details it sensitive one .... need a working function where i am going to replace the query from onwards `SELECT table_name from my_tables where DPNAME := keyword and DEPD := depid` with my actual query

Comment: That query is invalid; remove colons, i.e. `where dpname = keyword and depd = depid`

Comment: @cafopa2172 can you provide a demo version that reproduces the issue? You don't have to include sensitive details.